# Schedule Kettle job

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have the ETL process written using the [Kettle](http://community.pentaho.com/projects/data-integration). It performs data transfer from the operational data source (MS SQL on Windows) to the Data Warehouse (MySQL on Ubuntu).

[image]

I want to schedule the Kettle job(other) for daily execution for populating tables of dimensions and table of fact, to have my data actual and ready for analysis and reporting.

How can I schedule performing the Kettle jobs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your kettle installation directory are several batch files, among them `spoon.bat`, `pan.bat` and `kitchen.bat`. `Spoon` is the UI you already know, `pan` is a command line tool to run transformations (`.ktr` files) from the command line and `kitchen` is a command line tool to run kettle jobs (`.kjb` files).

for a simple schedule create a batch file that calls either kitchen.bat or pan.bat (depending on whether you want to run a transformation or a job). Then use the windows task scheduler to run your batch file with whichever schedule you want.

this for instance would run a kettle job, use basic logging and append the log content to a logfile

```
kitchen.bat /file:"c:\etl\my_first_job.kjb" /level:Basic > c:\etl\logs\logging_for_my_first_job.log
```

this is of course for windows. If you run kettle on linux, you can use cron and the respective .sh files in the kettle installation directory (`pan.sh` or `kitchen.sh`).

as kettle stores shared database connections in the user profile, make sure the user running the scheduled task has those connections in his profile, otherwise your transformations would fail.

Answer (score 1):

scheduling in pentaho is done by carte server. 
http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Carte+User+Documentation

using with your start step params scheduling and the carte server you will be able to schedule this kettle job when you want.

Comment: you are welcome, once your carte server is up, you will be able to execute from kettle in the carte remote server, and takes the scheduling from the START step params (clic over start step to schedule the job)